# Retrieve the biggest first component of a tuple

Tags: haskell

For all that matters, I must warn that I am learning Haskell and I don't know many of the functions pre-built in, so I will be using what I've learned so far.

I've written this, the best way I could, tried many things but can't get through.

```
minFst :: [(t, t1)] -> [(t, t1)]
minFst [] = []
minFst ((a,b):(a1,b1):xs) = if (a >= a1) then (a,b): minFst xs
                                         else (a1,b1): minFst xs
```

What I need with this function is this:

```
[(10,21), (3, 55), (66,3)] = [3,55]  -- Gives me the tuple with the lowest 'a'
```

EDIT: after the suggestion of removing ord function, doesn't give me errors compiling, only when i call the minFst:

```
minFst [(1,2),(4,5),(5,7),(2,5),(10,6)]
[(4,5),(5,7)*** Exception: Helder.hs:(584,1)-(586,72): Non-exhaustive patterns in function minFst
```

I hope you can help me with this one, if something is wrong with this post, please let me know and i'll change it, don't downvote me at first.

Comment: Why are you using the function `ord`?

Comment: Initially i wanted my function to compare chars, but i thought it would be easy to start out with Ints. You are right, let me remove the ord function.

Comment: @Rhymoid Changed the function, does not give me any error while compiling, but after calling it, gives me an error :(

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is that the recursive case takes two tuples off the list each time, so eventually you will be evaluating `minFst [(10,6)]` and there is no case for that!

Comment: @HélderMoreira are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Octoshape bheklilr gave me more than enough to solve this case, but thank you for the interest in this matter. Hope all the best to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple using some built in functions, `Data.List.minimumBy`, `Data.Ord.comparing`, and `fst`:

```
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

minFst :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
minFst xs = minimumBy (comparing fst) xs
```

Or you can write it point-free as

```
minFst = minimumBy (comparing fst)
```

---

Since you said that you can't use those functions for your assignment, let's start by writing a simple minimum function ourselves

```
myMin :: Ord a => [a] -> a
myMin [] = error "Empty list!"
myMin [x] = x
myMin (x:y:xs) = if x < y then myMin x xs else myMin y xs
```

Now, this won't work in your case since you want to find the tuple with the smallest element, so you'll have to modify this code a bit to

```
myMin :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
myMin [] = error "Empty list!"
myMin [x] = x
myMin ((a1, b1):(a2, b2):xs) = {- Implementation here -}
```

I'll let you fill that in yourself.  Now, if want all of the tuples with the smallest first element (there could be more than one), you can do it inefficiently by first calculating the minimum, then filtering the list for all that have that first element.  This isn't the best algorithm because you have to search the list twice.

---

If you want to do it in one pass, it gets as bit trickier.  In these situations, you want to accumulate the current minimums as you traverse.  Whenever you need to accumulate values, you'll need another argument, but it's best to hide this inside a local function, not a module-level one.  I'll show you an example for lists of integers:

```
minimums :: [Int] -> [Int]
minimums xs = go xs []
    where
        go [] acc = acc
        go (x:xs) (y:ys)
            | x == y = go xs (x:y:ys)  -- Accumulate the x
            | x < y  = go xs [x]       -- Reset if new min found
            | otherwise = go xs (y:ys) -- Ignore x if greater than y

> minimums [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 1]
```

Not very exciting for just `Int`s, but it'll give you the basic pattern needed to do this with tuples.  This function, like the built in `minimum`, can not be lazy, it has to evaluate each element in the list, so don't pass it an infinite list or you'll be waiting forever for it to finish.

Comment: Thank you, but i am not allowed to use it in my college, before we learn it. But thank you very much. I will try them and see if they work later on

Comment: What an answer sir!! :) . Thank you so much for the clarification. Couldn't ask for more. Wish i could upvote you more than once for this.